# Air Presure and Air Velocity from speaker

Tags: acoustics, pressure, velocity, air, vibrations

How do I determine/calculate the air pressure emitted from a speaker ? And how to determine the velocity of air from the sound air pressure ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure the sound level in decibels. This is a logarithmic scale where zero decibels corresponds to [a root mean square pressure of 20 micropascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Acoustics), and every 20 decibels corresponds to a tenfold increase in the pressure.

Once you have measured the sound level and calculated the pressure you can use the equation for the [particle velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_velocity):

$$ v = \frac{P}{Z} $$

where $Z$ is the [acoustic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance). The linked article includes a table of values for the acoustic impedance of air. For air at sea level and room temperature the acoustic impedance is about 415 Pa s/m.

Comment: So the particle velocity equals to the velocity of air? Thanks for the response.